# Is possible to hide the days before an after the current month in FullCalendar.js plugin

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using arshaw.com [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) jQuery plugin. By default it shows the current month days, but it also shows some days before and after (of the previous and next month) to fill the full grid from sunday to saturday.

Is there a way to hide this extra days, so the calendar month view shows only the current month days and leave empty the other spaces, or at least a way to hide and event that is registered on a different month, not in the actual one.

Answer (score 2):

In your event generator, skip events not in current month. Then add

```
.fc-other-month .fc-day-number {display:none;}
```

Comment: Just to note that you also need to set the weekMode to either liquid or variable, otherwise you will end up with extra rows. [see doc](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/weekMode/)

Comment: This works, but the dates are still loaded.. There has to be a better way to do this using the JS API.

Comment: That's why I suggested skipping the events (via function/json) for dates in other months. This was in an old version of FC, check the current API.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will hide the dates but not the events of past and upcoming events of other months:

```
.fc-day-number.fc-other-month {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* for IE */
}
```